# C# WPF value is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I got value is null in my code, which I don't quite understand. Here is my code:

```
public int[] Data
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                {
                    if (null != value)
                    {
                        _histogram[i] = value[i];
                    }
                }           

                RedrawHistogram();
            }
        }
```

The error occurs at

```
if (null != value)
                    {
                        _histogram[i] = value[i];
                    }
```

where `value` is `null`! I am wondering what is happening here? Even if I put a condition above, it still fails? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_histogram` is what is null, not `value`.  You'll need to initialize it as an `int[]` at some point in time.  Perhaps in each `set` call, perhaps once in the constructor, it's not clear which is desirable in your case.

Comment: I see. But _histogram is actually initialized as _histogram = new int[256]; in the constructor as I observed. And I have not found where it was destroyed yet.

Comment: Actually, it was the value that is null. The _histogram in a int[256]. I am pretty confused now.

Comment: @NickXTsui Well, you can debug the code to be sure, but given the code you've provided, it's *almost* impossible for `value` to be what's throwing the null reference exception.  You'd pretty much need to be deliberately trying for that to be the case.  For `_histogram` to be null would simply imply code you haven't shown is in error, which, until you have shown that code and it's not in error, is by far the more likely option.

Comment: @NickXTsui If `value` was indeed `null` then the most likely option is that you didn't show us the code you were actually executing, as having that code while also having `value` throw a NRE on the given line is *almost* impossible.  Of course the other option is that your exception is being thrown on a different line, and given the implementation of your `get` method, I wouldn't be surprised if it resulted in an exception down the road.